# SSL/TSL for React Frontend and Express Backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ssl

I have been learning more about web development so this is likely a dumb question or I do not have the knowledge to search for the answer properly.

I am revamping my current personal website (hosted on Github pages). I am making a React frontend which will be served via Github pages and with an Express backend (likely through cyclic). I want to add SSL/TSL Encryption for encrypted communication between the frontend and backend.

To my knowledge, SSL works via the server sending it's certificate to the client. It also will send it's public key so that the client can use the key to encrypt the message, send it to the server which uses the private key to decrypt said message. To me this means that I definitely would need to get a certificate for my backend.

However, I have some knowledge into how RSA encryption works (I know this is not the same) but it seems like this means that messages from the server to the client would not be secure. Would this mean that if I needed messages to be encrypted going that way that I would need to add a certificate. I personally cannot think of an example but I am sure there might be one.

First, is my assumption correct? If this is the case, how would I do so in both the general sense and with the services I am using?

Thank you for any help and I apologize for any mistakes I made, I figured to put out my thought process.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub pages will do the SSL/HTTPS for you but you as part of configuring your custom domain. See [Securing your GitHub Pages site with HTTPS](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https).

> In the "Code and automation" section of the sidebar, click  Pages.
>
> Under "GitHub Pages," select Enforce HTTPS.

If you were using your own servers, most people use Nginx to terminate SSL. Node.js can do it but most often Nginx is used as a reverse-proxy and SSL termination point.

Comment: Thank you. Forgive me for asking but was my assumption about the encryption working one way correct? What you did say made sense though, thanks!

Comment: Both requests and responses are encrypted. The browser says hello, the server responds with a certificate and the client generates a secret and shares it w the server. From then on both encryption and decryption use that shared secret.